# htaccess URL rewrite not working for sub folder

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a URL rewrite. I've looked all around on the net for a generator create a rewrite for this URL, but can't find anything that I'm looking for specifically. This is what I've come up with so far, though obviously, it isn't working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index/html/(.*)/ index.php?html=$1
```

The URL rewrite that I'm looking for would look like this.

**No rewrite:** http://example.com/asysc/code/index.php?html=some-text-here-

**Rewrite:** http://example.com/asysc/code/html/some-text-here

I've someone would be as so kind and helping me with the right rewrite would look like, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Jon

Comment: So the second URL is the one that you want to rewrite to something else? That doesn’t even contain `index/html/` anywhere, so how would you expect that rule to ever match?

Comment: Well the folder code would have a index.php or .html inside of it. So actually the no rewrite would be: http://example.com/asysc/code/index.php?html=some-text-here. Sorry, late night already for me.